# Apache block an ip address from accessing the website

Tags: apache, ip

someone trying to access pages like

> //mysqladmin//scripts/setup.php

Is it some hack attempt or .. ?

If yes then how i can block its ip from accessing mine website ?

Via htaccess or something else ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To block special IP addresses you can put the following in a .htaccess file located in your directory, you like to restrict:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 1.2.3.4
allow from all
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is the IP you like to block.

But note that IP adresses change users and also attackers change IP adresses.

So this will not secure your application and potentially block leagal visitors.

The better solution will be to make sure your script does not accept malicious paths.

1. Append a base path to the path you get from the user
2. Make sure the path you get from the user does not contain '../'

Comment: This answer should not be followed anymore with newer versions of Apache http server as this is depreciated and will be removed. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Answer (score 29):

As an update to this old question for those who still land here:

`Order Allow Deny` are deprecated as of Apache 2.4 and `Require` should be used.

An example of `Allow from all` to deny access to only IP 1.2.3.4.

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip 1.2.3.4
</RequireAll>
```

An example of `Deny from all` to allow access to only IP 1.2.3.4:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all denied
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
</RequireAll>
```

IP ranges, netmasks, CIDR notation, etc. can also be specified.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html (Deprecated)
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

Comment: I have to put this code within `<VirtualHost *:80>` and sibling to `<Directory /var/www/html>` in my virtual host file (`000-default.conf`)?

Comment: I put this directive like my comment above and not works. Where do I put this code?

Comment: @DR.Somar - The [context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) of these directives as stated in the manual is **directory, .htaccess**. If the _container_ is correct and it is not working the issue is likely with your configuration. Ensure the module is enabled (you probably just need `sudo a2enmod mod_authz_core`).

Comment: Tks your attention! I will try!

Comment: Then where is the directory`.htaccess` file, if apache2 is only used to serve an application running on a port at the localhost?

Comment: @James - You create the .htaccess file in the directory that you want the directives to apply to (and its subdirectories), see this [.htaccess tutorial](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html). To apply the directives at a configuration file level, run `apachectl -S` to see which configuration file you should edit.

Comment: So "Order Deny,Allow" would be replaced by "Require all granted" and "deny from 192.168.205.0/24" would be replaced by "Require not ip 192.168.205" ?

Comment: @Obewan - Your `Require` example will allow all except the subnet you have specified. CIDR notation is generally preferred (192.168.205.0/24).