# Apache logrotate and very large access_log file

Tags: apache, cron, bitnami, logrotate

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm running Bitnami LAMP stack on AWS Lightsail. My apache access_log file is consistently getting very large (1 gb per day). I've set it to rotate hourly (although appears only to be rotating daily despite moving the logrotate from cron.daily to cron.hourly).

I'm trying to understand what is going on and how to prevent it, or address it. The lines that appear to be filling up the file are as below:

```
xx.xx.xx.xxx - - [14/Sep/2022:09:29:35 +0000] "GET /images/items_thumbs/ HTTP/1.1" 404 196
```

There are about 20 requests like this per second, all from the same IP (obscured above). It also appears that when the access_log file is too large it causes the server to crash when rotation is attempted.

What have I tried? I've addressed a part of the site that was causing 404 errors for an image, I believe it was a javascript loop that kept trying to fetch a missing image (onerror). I've removed that code from the site. I'm wondering if it's possible a machine at that IP address still has the page open and the script is still running?

I can get away with not having an access_log if it's easy to disable this feature? I would still want the error_log however as it's very useful!

Comment: You could block the IP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264233/apache-block-an-ip-address-from-accessing-the-website

Comment: Or setup a permanent redirect (301) on that image to some other site.  That way the browser will only ask for it once, and any further request will be redirected by the browser, and not reach your machine.  **Third** block the IP directly in ip tables.